# Insert into Select From Delete

Tags: mysql, select, sql-delete

I want to transfer 50 rows from table1 to table 2, how should I do this?

Suggested code:

```
    INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 
    WHERE uid IN ('23','34','345','567','3242','34322','2') DELETE;
```

Comment: What does the DELETE at the end mean?

Comment: Does table1 and table2 have the same schema, and are you appending the rows to table2?

Comment: I don't know, I guess I saw it somewhere - what I want to do is delete the entries from table1 and move them (not copy them) to table2

Comment: did you try the suggested code? What the output of suggested code..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write 2 statements. If you usee InnoDB, put them inside a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION ;

INSERT INTO table2 
  SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE uid IN ('23','34','345','567','3242','34322','2') ;

DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE uid IN ('23','34','345','567','3242','34322','2') ;

COMMIT ;
```

Comment: You can use PHPMyadmin to run statements or scripts. What is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem, you asked, I answered

Comment: I didn't ask about your interface (PHPMyAdmin or other). I said to use a transaction if you are using the **engine** InnoDB. InnoDB and MyISAM are the two most common engines. Every table in MySQL belongs to an engine. See: [Storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html)

Comment: If you are the single user of the database, there is no need to use a transaction (although it doesn't hurt, you'll learn how things should be done in a db). If there are many concurrent users/connections, the transaction is a safety belt. If anything goes wrong during the 2 (or more) statements, the whole transaction is "rolled back". So, if the Insert fails, the rows are not deleted from table1. Even more, if someone else writes other rows with these uids in table1 (in the small fraction of time between your Insert and your Delete), those rows will not be deleted by your Delete.

Comment: done, using php my admin, i'm single user, no transaction, just 2 statements. all good. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2 WHERE col4='some value'
```

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3507171/Transferring-Data-from-One-Table-to-Another.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 'A'
```